# Why Elixir operator "in" will not work in for loops?

Tags: elixir, logical-operators

Just curious why I cannot use the "in" Elixir operator in a for loop. For example:

```
#does not work
list = [1, 2, 3]
for i in list do
    IO.puts i
end
```

Instead of this

```
#this works
list = [1, 2, 3]
for i <- list do
    IO.puts i
end
```

However when in an iex session I can do the following:

```
iex(1)> list = [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
iex(2)> 1 in list
true
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `in` operator has different semantic. `in` is for checking whether value is in range/list. It is similar to `Enum.member?/2`. On the other hand `<-` is interpreted as a "looping" (generator). This is done to allow `in` as a filter, ex.:

```
for i <- 1..100,
    r = rem(i, 5)
    i in [3, 4],
    do: i
# => [3, 4, 8, 9, …]
```

Comment: It's not only similar to `Enum.member?/2`, it actually translates to it

Comment: @sbacaro not really, because it behaves differently in guards. In guards it behaves differently depending on the arguments.

Comment: from the [Kernel docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#in/2): `This operator (which is a macro) simply translates to a call to Enum.member?/2`

Comment: [Except guards](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#in/2-guards), you cannot use `Enum.member?/2` in guards, but you can (partially) use `in`.

Comment: @sbacaro `Kernel.in/2` is way more complicated and is translated into `Enum.member?/2` only in [one specific case](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L3573-L3574). Trust code, not docs.